# Overwriting of objects in JAXB

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, lombok

I have a sample XML, would want to create objects and store them in a list.
The XML contains the following:

```
<students>
<student>
    <firstName>A</firstName>
    <id>1</id>
    <lastName>C</lastName>
    <company>BCD</company>
</student>
<student>
    <firstName>B</firstName>
    <id>2</id>
    <lastName>C</lastName>
    <company>EFG</company>
</student>
</students>
```

I create the classes
student.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@XmlRootElement
public class Student {

    private long Id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String company;
}
```

As well as Students.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@XmlRootElement
public class Students {
    
    private Student student;

}
```

And of course the Main program: ParsingXML.java

```
List<Students> listOfStudentsType= new ArrayList<Students>();   
        
        
        try {
            File xmlFile = new File("Student.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);                           
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();        
            Students employee = (Students) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile); 
            listOfStudentsType.add(employee);
           
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ListIterator<Students> litr = listOfStudentsType.listIterator();   
        //System.out.println(listOfStudentsType.size());
        //System.out.println("\n Using list iterator");
        while(litr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(litr.next());
        }
```

I want to store the objects in an internal list.
I expect it to have 2 entries of id 1 and 2.

However I get the following output

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/C:/Users/R.Premsagar/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.0-b170127.1453/jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Students(student=Student(Id=2, firstName=B, lastName=C, company=EFG))
```

Only the second entry is shown here. I believe it is getting overwritten. Could anyone provide me some insights to have both the values, please

---

Comment: I don't know this technology, but shouldn't that logically be `private List<Student> students;` in `Student`?

Comment: I have tried that, but gives a unexpected element exception

Comment: Until someone comes by here who knows this, it's possible [THIS](https://coderanch.com/t/595215/languages/Unmarshalling-nested-child-elements-jaxb) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious reason being you are not using the `List<Student>` for reaching the XML. Following is the complete solution for `unmarshalling` and `marshalling` the provided XML:

XML:

```
<students>
    <student>
        <firstName>A</firstName>
        <id>1</id>
        <lastName>C</lastName>
        <company>BCD</company>
    </student>
    <student>
        <firstName>B</firstName>
        <id>2</id>
        <lastName>C</lastName>
        <company>EFG</company>
    </student>
</students>
```

Students.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "students")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Students {
    @XmlElement(name="student")
    private List<Student> student;
}
```

Student.class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Student {
    @XmlElement(name="id")
    private long Id;

    @XmlElement(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @XmlElement(name="company")
    private String company;
}
```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("students.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Students students = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Students.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(students.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(students, System.out);
    }
}
```

This will provide following result:

```
Students(student=[Student(Id=1, firstName=A, lastName=C, company=BCD), Student(Id=2, firstName=B, lastName=C, company=EFG)])
<students>
   <student>
      <id>1</id>
      <firstName>A</firstName>
      <lastName>C</lastName>
      <company>BCD</company>
   </student>
   <student>
      <id>2</id>
      <firstName>B</firstName>
      <lastName>C</lastName>
      <company>EFG</company>
   </student>
</students>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is it mandatory to use InputStream and XMLStreamReader? Any suggestion on whether we could see the results using a simple for loop after unmarshalling? Ultimately, I want to add the student objects to a list

Comment: Na Na, you can use anything you would like. In my case, I am reading from the file so I used the `Inputstreamreader`. In this link, they have provided what are the types of input you can use for `Jaxb marshalling/unmarshalling` based on your choice you can use anything. As long as your JAXB is getting data it does not matter what you use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html  and the examples: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext/createJAXBIntrospector